# How to configure two kafka topics in mule connector?

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, mule-studio, mule-esb, mulesoft

I want to receive message from two kafka topics. How do i configure two kafka topics in mule?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with two kafka connector and its working.